# How to insert a character into a string in Nim

Tags: nim-lang

I need to insert a character into a string, knowing the insertion index. Can I do this without resorting to concatenation?

Before:

```
001D0FF180B2
```

After:

```
001D0FF180:B2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that using `system.insert`:

```
var s = "001D0FF180B2"
s.insert(":", 10)
echo s  # 001D0FF180:B2
```

Or `sugar.dup` if you don't want to do that in-place:

```
echo "001D0FF180B2".dup(insert(":", 10))  # 001D0FF180:B2
```